# Why is my home wifi network NOT working intermittently?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, timeout

My home Wi-Fi breaks intermittently. How can I troubleshoot it?

### Background

I use China Telecom service and they provide a smart SDN gateway which is fiber 1000 M speed. The wired network is working smoothly all the time.

The issue occurs with the Wi-Fi. It breaks intermittently. When it breaks, the Wi-Fi connection status shows normal, but no Internet access. The DNS time-outs.

### What I tried

- I tried all the well-known DNSs, for example, 8.8.8.8, 114.114.114.114, etc. No effect.
- I bought another dual frequency and dual 1000 M Wi-Fi router, same issue.
- I tried locking the signal channel, but no effect. Same issue.
- I tried connecting to the internet through the hotspot shared from the smartphone, no issue.

### More information

When DNS time-outs occur, the `tracert` shows:

[image]

And the browser shows (DNS_PROBE_xxx):

[image]

When no timeouts issue, the `tracert` shows:

[image]

What should I do to troubleshoot the root cause?

Comment: Do you experience the same break up if you create a WiFi hotspot with your smartphone? This is a simple way to rule out your broadband router and isolate the issue to your operating system.

Comment: Thanks, @Mastaxx! When I use my WIFI hotspot, the connection is steady and stable.

Comment: Sounds like your broadband provider may be able to help you now that you can prove there's nothing wrong with your PC by telling them it works fine from your smartphone hotspot. If they are a good provider they should be able to elevate your case from level 1 to level 2 support etc.. if the first person who speaks to you cannot help with the troubleshooting.